# Creating a memory-based game from two previous games

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a set of games to help children with deficiencies learn faster: The first game consists in a set of colors, and the user has to pick the right one from a set of four; the second one plays a sound and the user has to pick the animal/vehicle that is making that sound.
Each game consists in 6 levels of difficulty. For each level, the user has 3 chances to pick the correct answer. The games are played one after another (if the user can't pass one level in the first game, it will continue with the second game).

For the third game, I want to make a memory game from the previous two. Let's say the user didn't pass level 2 in the first game and level 3 in the second game. Then the third game will have 2 Intents: the first one will be randomly selected from the levels in the first game that he passed (in this case it will be the first or the second level), and the second one, from level 1, 2 or 3 -in this case- from the second game.

I was thinking in sending an integer through an Intent in every game after the user fails to pass it and use that number to select a level for the third game.
So far, I tried using this:
This is the first game:

```
if(contor2 == 3) //the user has no more chances left
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(FirstGame2.this, ThirdGame.class);
        intent1.putExtra("var1", 2); //the value of the current level

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstGame2.this, SecondGame1.class);
        startActivity(intent); //start the second game
    }
```

And in the second game:

```
if(contor == 3) //the user is out of chances
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(SecondGame3.this, ThirdGame.class);
        intent1.putExtra("var2", 3); //in the second game he didn't pass level 3, so we're sending the value "3"
        startActivity(intent1); //start the third game        
    }
```

In the third game I have the following code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("var1", 0);

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    final int intValue2 = intent2.getIntExtra("var2", 0);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The value of var1 is "+ intValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it returns "0", instead of "2", so I guess the data isn't sent after all....

Any other ideas of how can I implement the third game? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the first game, you put extra to **intent1** but you start activity with **intent**. So, you are not using this part of code:

```
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(FirstGame2.this, ThirdGame.class);
     intent1.putExtra("var1", 2); //the value of the current
```

And that's why you see the default value: 0.

If you want to pass something you can go directly to the third game or you pass var1 to second game, you collect it and send again to the third game. Ex:

```
intent1.putExtra("var2", 3);
intent1.putExtra("var1", 2); or intent1.putExtra("var1", getIntent().getIntExtra("var2", 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've used Shared Preferences in the end :) this solved my problem more quicker